# Append Newlines to All Files in a Directory in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, newline

I have a project in Visual Studio that can build and run successfully. I need to make it work in Linux. One problem is that the newline character is different from that in Linux, thus I'm getting tons of warnings saying that "no newline at end of file". Appending newline characters to all files one after another is tedious, I'm wondering whether there is a Linux command that I can use to perform the same operation (here, the operation is append newline to end of file) to all files in a directory in Linux?

Thanks in advance!

-Leonora

Comment: tag perl and you will get wizardry of the highest order

Comment: per @Gereon 's answer, copy to your linux machine, then run `dos2unx *`. If no `dos2unix`, search here for alternates. Good luck.

Comment: is it your source code that's having the trouble with newlines?

Comment: @SamIam, yes actually, some of my source code don't have newlines at the end at all, it's not only about the windows to linux conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most linuxes have a `dos2unix` command that helps with file conversions.

Comment: Thank you! So would this command work? find . -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix

Comment: or rather `find . -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -exec dos2unix {}\;`

Comment: Thank you. Your command works, the conversions were done, however I'm still getting some warnings about no newline at end of file. I think it's because in some files there aren't any newlines at all, not even in Visual Studio. So after the conversion it still has got no newlines. If I append newlines one file after another I would do echo "\n" >> someFile.cpp, but is there also a way to mass-produce that for all files in a directory?

Comment: if you really want to do this for **all** files, try `for f in *; do echo "\n" >>$f; done`